# Capybara Angular rspec testing for select dropdown form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, rspec, capybara

I have the following dropdown menu / select implemented in Angular.js:

```
<select id="user_accounts" ng-model="account_chosen" 
  ng-options="item.name for item in accounts">
  <option value="">All</option>
</select>
```

The accounts holds an array of objects: account A, account B, account C, which is rendered on the client-side for the user to see.

On the Capybara RSpec side, I want to integrate a test like so:

```
select('account A', from: "user_accounts")
```

However, running the test, I get an "Unable to find option 'account A' " error. How can I configure the test to select an option from the dropdown correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a driver like phantomjs or selenium you can do these things :

clicking by text selection :

```
find('#user_accounts').find(:xpath, "option[normalize-space(text())='account A']").select_option
```

or check wether the selectbox has the textitems :

```
element=find('#user_accounts')
element.should have_selector(:xpath, "option[normalize-space(text())='account A']")
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned which Capybara driver you're using, but if your test rely on client-side rendering, you'll need to be sure to use a driver that can execute JavaScript. The default RackTest driver cannot.

See https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#drivers for instructions on setting the driver to Selenium or another JavaScript-capable option.